# No se muestra la imagen, se debe agrandar la ventana para que recien se muestre... Java

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Saludos amigos programadores, en esta oportunidad me dirijo a ustedes para pedir ayuda de mi proyecto en Java.
Como dice el titulo, al compilar mi codigo, solamente se muestran mis letras sobre el panel, pero no la imagen, pero... cuando agrando solo un poco la ventana, recien aparece la imagen y de paso tambien mi caja de texto, porfavor alguien que me ayude con este problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No llego a leer el código.

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor, agrega el código como texto y no como imagen. Te recomiendo que pases por la página [ask] para que mejores tu pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenido @Bilongas para entender mejor tu pregunta editarla pon el código en texto no imágenes

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar la linea 44:

```
this.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

Y pon:

```
this.add(panel);
```

Si con eso continua sin funcionarte prueba cambiando la sentencia que te he dicho **this.add(panel);** y colocala en la linea 61, justo despues de **panel.add(cajaTexto);**

Espero que te ayude, es lo que puedo decirte sin poder ver bien todo tu codigo

Suerte amigo :)

Comment: Por cierto, recuerda que el metodo setBounds() en los parametros correspondientes al ancho y al alto del JLabel tiene que ser el mismo que el de la imagen si no, se te puede ver mal

Comment: Okey bro, lo implementare y vere lo que sucede... gracias por la ayuda